# Name clashing with class method

Tags: c++, sockets, posix, name-clash

So I have a class that is defined as below:

```
class Socket {
public:
    Socket();
    virtual ~Socket();

    int open();
    void close();

private:
    int mHandle;
    int mState;
};
```

Then I implement the close() method as such:

```
void Socket::close()
{
    if (mHandle!=0)
        close(mHandle);
}
```

The "close(mHandle)" inside my close is the one defined in  and AFAIK it is not within any namespace.

To workaround I renamed my close to something else, but there gotta be some other way...

Comment: Try `::close(mHandle);` to force looking up in the root namespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name lookup ends as soon as at least one function is found. You can qualify the name so it starts looking in the right place:

```
::close( mHandle );
```

Or declare the name locally so lookup bypasses the class members:

```
using ::close;
close( mHandle );
```

Comment: thanks! I've seen this ::notation before but never stopped to think what it really meant until now.